# exported video have flicker in Davinci Reslove

Tags: resolve, davinci, davinci-resolve

I've encountered an issue with DaVinci Resolve. As you can see in the image, there is a black bar present in all the exported videos.

[flicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQfJT.jpg)

This problem persists across all of my projects, and resetting the settings hasn't resolved it. I've searched online for a solution, but haven't found any answers. Here are my system specifications. Please guide me if you can: i5-8600 CPU Rx580 GPU 16 GB RAM

Answer (score 0):

Use Quicktime as export settings.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).